# Android JSONArray Exception

Tags: android, json, exception

I have a JSON like this :

```
{

- 0: {
    "title": "Title1",
    "content": "test"
},
 - 1: {
    "title": "Title2",
    "content": "test2"
}
}
```

So i want to recover it in my application, and i have an exception with this line :

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

I checked that "result" contains my `JSON`, and it's the case.

When i see the error in the logcat i just see values of my JSON.... i have something like that :

```
org.json.JSONException and values of my JSON
```

Could someone  help me ?

Comment: can you add complete logcat exception,if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**{**  means Object by means if json data starts with a  { than it is an object

**[**  means array by means if json data starts with a  [ than it is an array

use

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

instead of

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

for a simple tutorial and to learn visit

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Ok, i understood but i have a problem because me, i haven't a json object with name, i have just number, not "contacts" like your example. So how can i do a while on jObject ?

Comment: Please visit the documentation, you can iterate over the data and findout. you can obtain an object based on a particular key.

Answer (score 1):

The `JSON` you posted is not a `JSONArray` but a `JSONObject` so you have to change from

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

to

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Comment: Oh, ok. But now, how can i do to do a "while" on jObject ?

Comment: you still have the possibility to get an iterator with all the keys, do a while on that iterator and retrieve every object through optObject(). I'll strongly suggest you to give a look to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can get an easy to understand example for encoding and parsing json:
[Android JSON Tutorial: Create and Parse JSON data](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html)

and

[JSON in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)